# PDF reader feature (notes)

Tags: macos, pdf, pdf-reader

So when I read papers in hard copy, I like to be able to mark the line that I am reading currently using a notecard, which covers up things below the line that I am reading.  This keeps me from being distracted.  Is there a PDF reader that has a feature like this?  I realize that most of the time I *could* just use the bottom of the screen, but I was just wondering if there is a purpose built tool for this.  I use Mac OS X, by the way.

Comment: Dupe. Please don't. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/pdf-reader-feature

Comment: Sorry.  I'm really only duping because Apple SE is still in beta and doesn't get as much traffic as SuperUser

Comment: Then keep the one here and delete the one there. This is a software question so Super User is a better fit anyway.

Comment: Disable auto-resize of the PDF document and resize the window. Easier than the bottom of the screen and precision scrolling, dragging the window edge = moving the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) is a free app that should be able to help you with this:

> Skim is a PDF reader and note-taker for OS X. It is designed to help you read and annotate scientific papers in PDF, but is also great for viewing any PDF file.

It has a Reading Bar feature that can either highlight one line with a colour of your choice, or highlight all lines but one.  You can move the Reading Bar around with your mouse.  I hope this helps!